Text Mesh Pro object cannot be interacted with via gaze - unity 2022+mrtk3
In my project, I have two elements- a textmeshpro object and a sphere game object. For my use case, I should be able to make the text mesh object visible (initially invisible) by hovering over/ gazing at the sphere. Once the text becomes visible, I should be able to see it as long as I am gazing at it, and when I am no longer gazing at it, the text should disappear after 2 seconds. 
Currently, I am using mrtk3's GazeInteractor, and I was able to add the 'StatefulInteractable' component along with its 'MRTK events- is gaze hovered'—to the sphere, which makes the text visible, but when I do the same for my text mesh object, I am not able to implement my use case. Does gaze+'StatefulInteractable' component not work for text mesh pro objects ?
I could really use some help figuring out where I am going wrong with this one. 
Thanks!

Did you add a 3D collider component to the TextMeshPro? You need to add a collider to make it interactable.

Thank you for your response. I just added a box collider component to the text mesh pro object and it worked!
